# Python separate arrays of complex number into the real part and imaginary part, outputting 8*8 matrix

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cmath 
a = np.array([[complex(3,6),complex(7,9),complex(2,8),complex(6,5)],
           [complex(3,7),complex(7,9),complex(2,8),complex(6,5)],
           [complex(3,8),complex(7,9),complex(2,8),complex(6,5)],
           [complex(3,9),complex(7,9),complex(2,8),complex(6,5)],
           [complex(3,1),complex(7,9),complex(2,8),complex(6,5)],
           [complex(3,2),complex(7,9),complex(2,8),complex(6,5)],
           [complex(3,3),complex(7,9),complex(2,8),complex(6,5)],
           [complex(3,4),complex(7,9),complex(2,8),complex(6,5)],
           ])
l = np.array(['eval1_real','eval2_real','eval3_real','eval4_real','eval1_imag','eval2_imag','eval3_imag','eval4_imag'])
x = 1
for i in range(0, len(a),1):
        w = a[i]
        e1r = w[0].real
        e1c = w[0].imag
        e2r = w[1].real
        e2c = w[1].imag
        e3r = w[2].real
        e3c = w[2].imag
        e4r = w[3].real
        e4c = w[3].imag
        p = np.array([e1r, e1c, e2r, e2c, e3r, e3c, e4r, e4c])
        m = np.insert(l,x,p,0) 
        x = x + 1
```

I tried for loop to separate but i cannot get those number to form together to become a full matrix
Is there a way to separate it altogether without using a loop or some array function i can put those together?

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to use `numpy-builtin` functions for elemental operations on all elements. You can try,

```py
result = np.dstack(
  np.apply_along_axis(
    lambda x: [x.real, x.imag], 0, a)
  ).flatten().reshape(8,8)
```

[numpy.apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

[numpy.dstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html)

Comment: What if i have a very large number if complex number that are always n*4, i and i dont know the number of n,how to separate those if that is the case?

Comment: Also, what if the complex number have a lot f decimals and i want them al to print 14 decimals ?

Comment: @rrryy39 I will suggest You to edit ur question or start a new with sufficient details as its not very clear what ur trying to achieve.